# Join based on min

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

```
Table1:
id, date

Table2:
id,date
```

Both the table contain information about id. Table1 and Table2 can have some extra rows which are not present in another table.

```
Example:
Table1:
1,15-Jun
2,16-Jun
4,17-Jun

Table2 
1,14-Jun
2,17-Jun
3,18-Jun
```

I need a summarize result which give minimum date for each row. 
Expected result:

```
1,14-Jun
2,16-Jun
3,18-Jun
4,17-Jun
```

Comment: Please search before posting questions. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877062/select-max-min-values-from-two-tables

Comment: A side remark: As you may see from some of the answers, it is not considered a good idea to call a column date. You can use it such as in `select "date" from table1`, but it is recommended not to use reserved words for column names.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ya thanks. I used that as example to easily understanding of datatype if required.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, min(date_) from (
    select id, date_ from table1 
    union all
    select id, date_ from table12
) group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MIN(date)
FROM (SELECT id, date
      FROM Table1
      UNION
      SELECT id, date
      FROM Table2)
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  with a as(select t.i_id,t.dt_date from t
union 
select b.i_id,b.dt_date from b)
select a.i_id,min(a.dt_date) from a group by a.i_id order by a.i_id;
```

You can check  [this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8df85/2)

Comment: @LalitKumarB How can you claim this is just duplicate answare from your answar you cun't expect that way of doing a same work will different didderent.